# NameError: name 'parse_config' is not defined

Tags: python, configparser

I am trying to set up a set of scripts I got from github. I have a utils.py file that has the bellow python code:

```
p_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/"
username = getpass.getuser()
myData = parse_config(p_dir+"../config/data.config")
myPars = parse_config(p_dir+"../config/parameters.config")
myPipelines = parse_config(p_dir+"../config/pipeline.config")
```

When I run the script I get the bellow error:

```
myData = parse_config(p_dir+"../config/data.config")
NameError: name 'parse_config' is not defined
```

I thought that the required module has not been imported but it seems that thats not the case as I get the same error when I import configparser. Any idea on which module the parse_config()might belong or in general on how to fix the error?
Thanks in advance :) !

Comment: You probably want to use either `from configparser import parse_config` or `configparser.parse_config`

Comment: `I get the same error when I import configparser` import how? Please show us. Assuming that `configparser` is the correct module - if you're doing `import configparser` then you'd have to refer to that function via `configparser.parse_config`. If you did `from configparser import *` or `from configparser import parse_config` then you code wouldn't have that error.

Comment: can you add link to the github page you got the script from?

Comment: @C.Nivs `configparser` does not have a `parse_config` function.

Comment: Here is the script https://github.com/YichaoOU/HemTools/blob/master/utils/utils.py

Comment: `parse_config` is defined a few other times in that same repo.  Not sure which one is correct, but presumably it is one of [these](https://github.com/YichaoOU/HemTools/search?q=parse_config).

Comment: from configparser import *
I get errors in both config_parse() and configparser.config_parse()

Comment: it's from this file: https://github.com/YichaoOU/HemTools/blob/master/utils/input_utils.py   he import from there 3 lines before (line 209)